# The import java.text.SimpleDateFormat cannot be resolved

Tags: java, java-15

I use Java 15 for my example.
I used Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2020-12.

I got an error shown below when I define SimpleDateFormat to handle with formating a date object.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; // error -> The import java.text.SimpleDateFormat cannot be resolved
```

How can I fix my issue?

Comment: By the way, that terrible `SimpleDateFormat` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by [`java.time.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the correct Execution environment or alternate JRE:

Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Libraries --> Double click JRE System Library.

Comment: I used jdk 15.0.2

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and/or closing and opening it?

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed.

Comment: @TonyBrand Java version is not the issue. That class has been in all but the original version of Java, from Java 1.1 through today’s 17. Edit your question to indicate your tooling. Are you using an IDE? Which one? What version of that IDE? If using an IDE, learn how to reset its internals. For example, when IntelliJ gets screwed up we have to execute "Invalidate caches".

Comment: @BasilBourque I used Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2020-12.

Comment: @TonyBrand Post your additional facts as edits to the Question, not as Comments.

Answer (score -1):

Just copying Basil comment without the toxicity:

SimpleDateFormat class was supplanted some time ago by java.time classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by java.time.DateTimeFormatter